# Chinese Poem Crossword Puzzle

Tags: poetry

Hiiiii
Here is a crossword puzzle about Poems!
[image]

1: Do you love me?
2: Mid-autumn barbecue
3: Ching Ming so many rain
4: Ghosts come from rain, Emperors come from clouds
5: I want to beat west
6: Eight thousand miles
7: Qin and Han
8: Pine trees. Moon?

Comment: I don't think it is real. Too many character squares, Idiom usually come in a 4 characters set

Comment: 第四句紛打頭，雲其中，十三個字，說的又是鬼神，很像屈原的東西，但又想不起來

Comment: Sorry it should be 14 words

Answer (score 2):

An Idiom puzzle should looks like this

[image]

1.continuously non-stop like river

2.one column supports the sky

3.full of natural resources

4.forever young

5.gain without working for it

6.extremely trendy

一. a column that withstands strong river flow

二. having a skill

三. mature age

四. the end of time

五. needs from time to time

Answer below:

~

~

~

~

[image]

1.川流不息 (continuously non-stop like river)

2.一柱擎天 (one column supports the sky)

3.地大物博 (full of natural resources)

4.長春不老 (forever young)

5.不勞而獲 (gain without working for it)

6.盛極一時 (extremely trendy)

一.中流砥柱 (a column that withstands strong river flow )

二.一技之長 (having a skill)

三.春秋鼎盛 (mature age)

四.天荒地老 (the end of time)

五.不時之需 (needs from time to time)

Comment: Where did you get this? Do you know where I could find more?

Comment: @Stephen Cowley I just made one up on my own. It took me a few minutes

Comment: @Stephen Cowley Just curious, how long it took for you to solve this puzzle? I presume a native Chinese can finish it in just few minutes.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive... Haha, I didn't solve it; I'm only vaguely familiar with a few of the answers. I gave it to my wife to try (native Chinese but college education in the states). She got most of them in about 20 minutes.

Comment: This puzzle only has 11 idioms, I think I can make something up with 30-40 of them, but I am not sure if it  is acceptable to post it as a question for everyone to try

Answer (score 1):

3# 清明时节雨纷纷

6# 八千里路云和月

7# 秦时明月汉时光

8# 明月松间照

Comment: The heading of the OP's post should be 'poem' crossword Puzzle

Answer (score 1):

1#高秋暮落蒹葭雨，顾盼伊人东水湄。（我编的(๑>؂<๑））

2#中秋高宴会

3# 清明时节雨纷纷

4# 纷纷雨外灵均过，瑟瑟云中帝子归

5# 我欲西征君又东

6# 八千里路云和月

7# 秦时明月汉时关

8# 明月松间照

另及：显然灵均、帝子并非ghost和emperor，此处应该也不是指词士、王子，而是自屈原用时之本义，泛指神灵，一是应鄱阳湖楚地之实，二是赞其灵异。虽然其他提示似乎也有望文生义之弊，不过似乎这样比较容易做出答案（笑）

Comment: hen厲害！但是 1,2,5 不對

Comment: 我這樣做是爲了讓大家更容易回答

Comment: 畢竟不是很多人知道屈原是誰,靈和帝直譯就是ghost和emperor